# How to unpack all values in a range of list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, unpack

So, I hope it is quite easy but can't realize it in a compact way.

The idea is that you have 2 numbers, that create a range, like: `range = [-3,2]`, and we want to create a tuple or list, no matter, with all values in this range: `new_range = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]`.

How can this code be implemented to not lose last number:

```
range = [-3,2]
new_range = []
for i in range(*range):
   new_range.append(_) 

print(new_range) result is: new_range = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1]
```

Is it possible not to lose last number withoud implementation of more multiline code?
Cause actule we can add smth like: `new_range.append(new_range[len(new_range)-1] + 1)` but it looks terrible as for me

Comment: Let's avoid the built-in `range` as your variable name here.  Hint - `last_num + 1` in range(first, last +1)`

Comment: `rng = [-3,2]; result = list(range(rng[0],rng[1] + 1))`

Comment: try this: `print(*range(*rng))`, <- `rng = [-3,2]`

Comment: and please don't use the [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) of python as variable; like `range`

Comment: Just add 1 to the second number before calling `range()`.

Comment: `rng = [-3, 2]; list(range(rng[0], rng[1]+1))` if you want inclusive range?

Comment: @DanielHao, thought about this, but idea is that user inputs star and end. Hm.... But maybe you are right....

Comment: @Serhei I don't see how getting the input from the user affects what Daniel said.

Comment: @Serhei The only thing Daniel said was that you shouldn't use the name `range` for your variable, because that will replace the built-in function with the same name.

Comment: @I'mahdi when you said "and please don't use built-in function of python as variable", ehat does it mean?! Cause I'm new man with programing

Comment: @Serhei Use `my_range = [-3, 2]` instead of `range = [-3, 2]`. Because `range` is the name of a built-in function -- after you assign to it, you can't call the function any more.

Comment: @Serhei, Barmer give you an anwser and can check this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) too.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html <--- @Serhei  pls read this.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, must explaine :) when we wrote 'ange(first, last +1)`' I just saw that I make this "range" condition, so to speak, more complicates as it must be,

Comment: When you wrote `range = [2,3]` that changed the `range` function to a list.  That breaks your code.  Don't use the names of built-in functions as variables.

Comment: Thank you everyone!!! I think ```range(rng[0], rng[1]+1)``` is the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

```
my_range = [-3,2]   #we camt use 'range' word as variable cause it is name of the function
new_range = []
for i in range(my_range[0], my_range[1] + 1):
   new_range.append(_) 

print(new_range) result is: new_range = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```